# Accessing static content in Jboss EAP 6.0

Tags: jboss7.x, jboss-eap-6

I am newbie and seek some guidance on accessing static content in Jboss EAP 6.0 using symbolic links.
During my search, I found solutions for Jboss 5/6 however I was not able to map it to EAP version we have.

We have 1000+ PDFs located on our app server and users would access it via the Web application.
In EAP 6.0 when creating a symbolic link inside a deployed ear/war the PDFs are not accessible from web browser.

If anyone has done this before or has any suggestions on how it can be in EAP then please let us know.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** Create a servlet that knows where to get those files from and let it serve them.

**Longer version/Explanation:**

Create a servlet, map it to e.g. `/yourapp/pdfs/*`:

```
@WebServlet("/pdfs/*")
public class PdfServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
        String basePath = getServletContext().getInitParameter("basePath");
        File f = new File(basePath + File.separator + req.getPathInfo());
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ////  BIG WARNING:                                               ////
        ////  Normalize the path of the file and check if the user can   ////
        ////  legitimately access it, or you created a BIG security      ////
        ////  hole! If possible enhance it with system-level security,   ////
        ////  i.e. the user running the application server can access    ////
        ////  files only in the basePath and application server dirs.    ////
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        if( f.exists() ) {
            OutputStream out = res.getOutputStream();
            // also set response headers for correct content type
            // or even cache headers, if you so desire
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int r;
            try( FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f) ) {
                while( (r=fis.read(buf)) >= 0 ) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, r);
                }
            }
        }
        else res.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

The code above may beed some tweaking but generally it outlines the solution...

Now specify the context init parameter in `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>basePath</param-name>
    <param-value>/the/path/to/the/pdfs</param-value>
</context-param>
```